# SQL Server Insert trimmed and concatenated values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values from different variables into one column, can you guys check my codes?

> Here is my SQL Server script, I am not that very familiar with sql server, btw I have my working script below on mysql version. you can check it for reference on what I want to happen here

```
(SELECT
    concat(LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd1)) AS HomeAdd1),
    ' ',
    (LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd2)) AS HomeAdd2),
    ' ',
    (LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd3)) AS HomeAdd3),
    ' ',
    (LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd4)) AS HomeAdd4),
    ' ',
    (LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd5)) AS HomeAdd5) as Residence,
```

> This is my working MySQL code

```
concat(trim(AltHome1),' ',trim(AltHome2),' ',trim(AltHome3),' ',trim(AltHome4),' ',trim(AltHome5)) as AltAdd,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the table aliases and fix some logic, this should work:

```
SELECT (LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd1)) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd2)) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd3)) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd4)) + ' ' +
        LTRIM(RTRIM(HomeAdd5))
       ) as Residence,
```

And for reference, the MySQL code should use `concat_ws()`:

```
concat_ws(' ', trim(AltHome1), trim(AltHome2), trim(AltHome3), trim(AltHome4), trim(AltHome5)
         ) as AltAdd,
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually replace the alias with the + sign but it is not working on me earlier because of "," I really appreciate your help!